# debug c# webmethod from ajax call?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a asp.net (web forms) c# code behind page that has a web method which I call from an ajax call on the same page.

I am getting a generic "Internal server error has occured" after the ajax POST call.

I would like to step through the web method code to determine what is happening.

How can I do this? Breakpoints are not hit. Is there a process I have to attach to? I can't find any info on what process would be running on my local IIS that handles WebMethod calls?

Note: I can debug and step through normal event response functions such as `Page_Load` and others.

ajax code:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Patrol/Report.aspx/GetSPResults",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify(postData)
}).done(function (result) {
    var results = "";
    if (result.d.length > 0) {
        results = JSON.parse(result.d);
    }
    buildViewModel(results);
    kendo.bind($("#Report"), viewModel);
    $("Checkpoints").fadeIn(100);
}).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
    alert("An error has occurred: " + err);
});
```

web method:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static string GetSPResults(string reportId, string sproc, Dictionary<string, string> parameters, string[] ensureArrays)
{
    Int32 intReportId;
    Console.WriteLine("Report.aspx/GetSPResults called");
    if (Int32.TryParse(reportId, out intReportId))
    {
        AV.Data.SqlSPHelper avdata = new AV.Data.SqlSPHelper(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ProductionConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        Dictionary<string, string> sprocCheckParams = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            {"Sproc", sproc},
            {"ReportID", reportId}
        };
        XElement sprocCheck = avdata.ExecuteSPXmlXElement("[dw].[spReport_Sproc_Check]", sprocCheckParams, null);
        if (sprocCheck.GetAttributeVal("result") == "1")
        {
            XElement result = avdata.ExecuteSPXmlXElement(sproc, parameters, null);
            result = result?.RemoveAllNamespacesAndNils();
            if (result != null)
            {
                var jsonResults = JsonConvertWrapper.SerializeXelement(result, ensureArrays, true, Formatting.Indented, true);
                return jsonResults;
            }
        }
    }
    return string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: is there an associated `.aspx` file for this code..? if so do you have the `CodeBehind` property pointing to your `.cs` file.. can you show the header of the .aspx page..?

Comment: @MethodMan I can do this for you, but I am able to step through the code behind successfully on the normal event functions, such as `Page_Load` does this debunk your theory or would you still want to see it?

Comment: perhaps you have some page errors happening .. it's really hard to tell whats going .. based on the code that you have posted..

Comment: @MethodMan I would think a page error would show up with a meaninful .NET error. Not sure what the ambiguous server error message means, this is my first time using C# web method

Comment: @madasunaga I think you misinterpreted my meaning. MethodMan was suggesting perhaps my code-behind page was not properly configured to be associated with my aspx page, I was replying with the proof that I step through the `Page_Load`, therefore it is correclty attached. This is not concerning the ajax call directly

Comment: Attach to your w3wp.exe process or iisexpress.exe whichever is hosting your web app.  The debugger will stop on the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Ok problem was the argument name for my post requests did not match the argument name in the WebMethod function signature.

POST request had argument name `reportID` when the WebMethod expected `reportId`